# What type of holly is this?

Tags: identification

These small holly bushes (1-2 feet tall and wide) came with the house, and I'm trying to figure out what species they are. They've got spiny leaves, which look like either a variety of American or English holly - but it's important to me to know which, because I'm trying to plant native (and I want to know how big they're going to get).

[image]
[image]

Comment: As @ Ecnerwal comments , the leaves need to be more clear. My first guess would be Burford . I doubt American because of the shine on the leaves. Burford comes in a few types including dwarf. What is the location ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 the location is northeastern US, if that helps?

Comment: Not Burford ( poor guess). As you say ,likely English or American ,although it does not match very well with the low gloss my American Hollys.  Burford does not do well in zone 7 ( too cold) , American does alright in warmer side of zone 5.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up IDing as **American Holly** (probably a cultivar, as the species is rarely planted in gardens).

- Leaf shape is characteristic of either English or American (Chinese also has spiked leaf edges, but in a symmetrical "horned" arrangement that is hard to confuse with English/American). Despite the many species of holly in the world, only these species have the stereotypical spiny leaves.
- Everyone says difference in glossiness is the key ID factor, but that's hard to tell when you don't have them side-by side.
- The key is to grab a fistful of leaves in your hand: if they fold easily and don't stab you, it's probably English holly. But these leaves *hurt* when grabbed!

There's one significant dwarf cultivar of American holly, the **Maryland Dwarf**. But the leaves of this cultivar look nothing like the leaves pictured in the question:

[image: Maryland dwarf holly close-up]

Since American holly is very slow growing (as little as 6 inches a year) it's perfectly possible for this to be one of the larger cultivars even if it was planted multiple years ago.